# Scope with Brackets in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any case in which putting code within brackets to reduce its scope is something that I might want to do, or is this one of those cases in which you guys will tell me, "If you need to do that in your code, then your code is badly written."

For example:

```
//***CODE****
{
  int foo=stuff;
  //use foo, and then I'm done using it forever
}
//****MORE CODE****
```

Comment: There's actually some few cases when it's still required.  Within cases for example.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, because this has the advantage that any local variables in that block will be destroyed at the end of the block.  This is especially useful if you have some kind of scope guard that you want to release as soon as possible, e.g.,

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
    // use protected objects
}   // release the_mutex
```

Note, however, that the use of a scope block like this is indicative of your code needing to be refactored:  the contents of the block can usually be split out into a separate function, which can be named and reused.

Comment: You imply it after, but I think that should be "use of a scope block like this is **often** indicative of your code needing to be refactored". Sometimes this is perfectly valid 'in the middle' of a function, and moving things out to a separate function - for the sake of adhering to some stringent coding convention - is awkward or, at best, tedious. _e.g._ if the 'temporary' scope needs to access many variables from the outer scope, it seems pointless to create a function, possibly for one-off use, and suffer the hassle/overhead of passing it all needed outer variables.

Comment: We also like to use such scoping brackets to restrict the scope of `using` directives (even if, of course, we warmly recommend to write out the namespace in all cases).

Comment: I am getting "expected a declaration" error when using this kind of blocks, but why ?

Comment: Is it possible to put an "if statement" before "//use protected object" with a condition to jump out from the scope (so to the end "}"), so the "//use protected objects" would never be executed? (something similar to "return 0" within a function).

Answer (score 6):

I have found another use case in my own code: unit testing destructors. Example using UnitTest++ (but the same principle applies regardless of unit testing framework):

```
TEST(SomeTest)
{
   {
   SomeClass someObject;
   } // someObject is destroyed
   CHECK(isSomeClassDestructorWorking())
   // e.g. have all resources been freed up?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For example, if you use the RAII idiom this may be useful. Synchronization locks for example.

In most case, the scope of a method should be small enough for such locks. There are times when you want to limit the lock scope for either performance, or to avoid sending a gazillion parameters to a refactored method. Using this trick shouldn't be too common, though.

Answer (score 5):

With all the things you can do in C++, adding a scope would really be the least of them.  There is nothing wrong with the code you have, I do it sometimes (often in a case to ensure the locals are restricted to the case).  Depending on the use you may like to think about refactoring the code into a separate function.

Answer (score 3):

Another place bracket scoping makes sense is inside macros.  For example, you could define a macro that declares variables of potentially the same name as variables inside the code block into which the macro is placed.

Answer (score 0):

An example is using it for a `using` directive to limit its scope so that you can avoid writing the namespace every time. Just makes the code shorter.

```cpp
// MyNamespace contains variables var1, var2, var3 etc.
{
using MyNamespace;

foo(var1, var2, var3);
foo(var4, var5, var6);
}
```

Outside of above scope you would access the variables as usual, so `MyNamespace::var1` etc.

That's what's possible, if that is part of a good design is another question.