# Statement blocks without a keyword in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scope with Brackets in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072845/scope-with-brackets-in-c)

I'm dealing with v8 javascript engine, developing a learning enviroment for new students in my university, and i step up with this:

d8.cc:309

```
char* input = NULL;
{  // Release lock for blocking input.
  Unlocker unlock(isolate);
  input = fgets(buffer, kBufferSize, stdin);
}
```

1. What's its name?
2. How can I use it in other contexts?
3. Is only fair in c++?

Comment: See [Scope with brackets in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072845/scope-with-brackets-in-c).

Comment: You aren't making sense. Rephrase the question in a sensible way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overall structure (i.e. an unnamed block) is known as a *compound-statement* as far as the language standard is concerned.  It serves to introduce a new scope.

In C++, there are generally two uses for this:

1. To limit a local variable to a particular section of code; the aim being to minimise scope "pollution", and to make it easier for the reader of the code.  (The same can be achieved in other languages, like C and Java.)
2. Tightly controlling the lifetime of an object/resource, because the destructor of scope-local variables will be automatically called at the end of the scope.  This can be used for several clever things, e.g. automatically closing file handles, releasing mutexes, and so on.  So you may hear people talk about e.g. *scoped mutexes*. (C and Java don't have destructors, so this concept doesn't translate.)

Comment: To answer part (3): It is legal in C also, but not as useful since C99 allows variable declarations anywhere.  In C++ the primary advantage is that variables scoped to the new block have their destructors called at the end of the block.  That appears to be the purpose here.

Answer (score 3):

It has no name, it is a block of code. The braces put an explicit lifetime on the lock controlled by Unlocker.

This is a perfectly valid technique in C and C++. It's a little more likely to be seen in C++ where RAII is used to limit the lifetime of an object and provide timely release of resources (such as locks), though it is quite useful in C to make the lifetime of a variable clear to the reader.

Comment: Annotation: In C and C++, a scope doesn't only control the lifetime, depending on the lifetime, the visibility of (temp) variables declared inside is limited to their scope. A variable declared within such a scope is therefore not accessible from enclsing scopes. But one must be careful, since declarations in scopes shadow identifiers with the same name from enclosing scopes!