# Switch statement code without a label

Tags: c, switch-statement, c89

How come ANSI C allows extraneous code before any case labels within a switch statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const int foo = 1;

  switch (foo) {
      printf("wut\n"); /* no label, doesn't output */
    case 1:
      printf("1\n");
      break;
    default:
      printf("other\n");
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
$ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi test.c
```

It compiles without warnings and executes fine - sans *"wut"*.

Comment: It's a scope, useful if you want to define variables only for the switch. If I may ask - why do you find it surprising?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum but nothing actually runs up in there - `"wut"` is not outputted. Why?

Comment: Sorry for the self-plug, but this answers your question exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023601/can-i-put-code-outside-of-cases-in-a-switch/29023816#29023816

Comment: Because it's not meant for that (it's not a case), it's meant for auxiliary declarations - for example if you want to declare an `int` to use in all cases (and nowhere else) it'd be a good place.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Oh awesome, thanks. Marking as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to put statements in `switch` without any label. Standard says about that:

#### C11: 6.8.4.2 The switch statement (p7):

> In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>     int i = 4;
>     f(i);
>     case 0:
>         i = 17;
>         /* falls through into default code */
>     default:
>          printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is **never
>   initialized**, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the `printf` function will
>   access an indeterminate value. Similarly, **the call to the function `f` cannot be reached**.

Comment: c11 != c89 (ANSI). Just pointing that out.

Comment: No. ANSI C refers to either C89 or C90. That is what the `-ansi` flag on GCC/CLang do, as well. It's ANSI C because it's the only C standard that compiles cleanly in all C++ compilers.