# How to limit scope of variable needed to construct object that lives longer?

Tags: c++, scope, api-design, raii

I have an object on the stack that requires another object for it's constructor, like this:

```
{
    ObjectDef def(importantData);  // should die as soon as obj is created
    def.setOptionalData(100);

    Object obj(def);  // should live for the remainder of the function body
}
```

Ideally, I like to put variables like `def` in their own scope.  This gives me the name "def" back, and makes it clear that it isn't useful anymore.

For example, what happens here with `result` I would like to do with `obj`:

```
// scope block
{
    int result = complexFunction() + anotherFunction();
    printf("the result is %i", result);
    doMoreThingsWithIt(result); 
}
// "result" is now gone
```

The problem though, is that there is no way to do that here, that I can see.  The constructor of `Object obj` cannot be before the scope because it's constructor needs `def`, and it cannot be within the scope because `obj` needs to survive much longer than `def`.

Is there anyway to accomplish limiting `def`'s scope to be shorter than `obj`, or should I just accept that it has to stay in scope for at least as long?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you rephrase your question. This is what I get (correct me if I'm wrong): you have a block of code, in that block you want to instantiate 2 objects ObjectDef and Object. For each object's constructor you want to pass some data via its constructor. What do you mean by "the constructor can not be before the scope" ... who's scope? Please rephrase.

Comment: You can use a boost::optional for deferred construction. Make the object, then construct it in an inner scope where `def` lives. Then `def` dies. However, I wouldn't call this cleaner than just naming `def` something specific enough not to interfere with future variable names in this function.

Comment: Why are you trying to control the lifetime of the object using scope when you could use new/delete operators, or the malloc/free functions that are specifically designed to manage object lifetimes?

Comment: @Nactus - I edited it to hopefully convey what I'm after better;

Comment: @ginkner because this is C++ and scope is by far the preferred way to manage lifetimes in idiomatic modern C++.

Comment: If you're set on that, then I think the best thing to do is to either use the lambda method, or create a function that returns the constructed object (or a copy, since you seem averse to using pointers). That way def is destroyed when you want it to be and the calling function gets it's initialized object. The only other real option is to use the terrible inline scope option, or some weird form of it (I've seen someone use if(true) to define a scope. Gag).

If possible, you could also change you're Object constructor to take importaintData and any other optional arguments.

Comment: ginkner - did they know the brackets alone can define a scope?  as for pointers, I don't mind them, I just want to avoid allocating data needlessly since there's overhead and requires checking if the allocation was successful

Comment: @Clairvoire I'm not sure. It was also in C#, where I'm not sure the inline scope works, but either way it was terrible. It looks to me like you're going to need to weigh the cost of allocating onto the heap with the cost of copying the Object back to a calling function. If you go the heap route, a unique_ptr might be a good way to keep to your idiom while still allowing for some good pointer action.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072845/scope-with-brackets-in-c   `Note, however, that the use of a scope block like this is indicative of your code needing to be refactored: the contents of the block can usually be split out into a separate function, which can be named and reused.` The answer to that question precisely predicted the most-upvoted answer to this question, ironically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a lambda:

```
Object obj{[&]{ ObjectDef def{importantData}; def.setOptionalData(100); return def; }()};
```

If `ObjectDef` frequently needs it's optional data set and this is a common pattern, consider adding a constructor to `ObjectDef` that allows optional data to be set or creating a named helper function that does the job the lambda does here.

Comment: Upvote for this, but don't you have too many semi-colons in there? I think `();` should just be `()`.

Comment: Upvoted, with the caviat that a normal function would probably perform very slightly faster.

Comment: @ginkner you can drop the caveat, a normal function will not perform faster.

Comment: @mattnewport caviat altered. Since lamdas are implemented by creating a class with an overloaded () operator, you have the overhead of memory allocation, capture shtuff, and method call rather than a global function call . You're right in that it's not likely to be MUCH slower, but if you ran it some large number of times you might see a small decrease in performance.

Comment: I really like this!  I had to rework it a little for VS2010 to take it though.  `Object obj([&]()->ObjectDef{ ObjectDef def(importantData); def.setOptionalData(100); return def; }());`

Comment: @ginkner no, lambdas do not have any overhead for memory allocation when used like this - they have automatic storage (allocated on the stack) and the function call is not virtual so it has no additional overhead relative to a global function call. In practice, any compiler that supports lambdas will inline code like this in an optimized build so there will be no overhead over writing the code the way it was written in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an object on the stack that requires another object for it's constructor.

**If the construction of an object requires multiple steps, create a factory function for it, and consider it a part of the type's API.**

This is a good rule to follow for API design:

- when you write client code, it will be clean from the start (and copy-paste does not create duplicate code for the instantiation)
- the instantiation code becomes testable and mockable;
- if you need another set of steps for instantiating an `Object`, you just create another factory function, near the first (naturally centralizing ways to instantiate this type into the same source file).
- this will allow you to hide any extra dependencies in the instantiation code for `Object`, into the .cpp file defining `Object`'s methods (for example, sparing you from having to `#include <ObjectDef.hpp>` in client code).

Your client code should always require a single line for instantiating an object:

```
auto make_object(Data &importantData, int optional = some_default)
{
    ObjectDef def(importantData);  // should die as soon as obj is created
    def.setOptionalData(optional);

    return Object{ std::move(def) }; // def dies here
}
```

client code:

```
auto obj = make_object(data); // about as short as calling a constructor
auto def = 0; // "def" identifier is free
```

Answer (score 1):

The more I think about it, the more I think you need a factory function/method. The lambda method will work fine if this is the only object you need, but if you need to capture the optional arguments or use the lamda in multiple places it could become...messy.

My advice is to define either a global function or a static method on Object (or possibly a new ObjectFactory class) that will take in importaintInfo and some additional options, and return you a fully constructed Object instance. That way you're ObjectDef never lives longer than it takes to construct the Object.

I'd really question the aversion to pointers and heap allocation, though, and It'd be helpful to know why you need to destroy ObjectDef so quickly. I'm assuming that it either has a handle to a locked resource, or is security critical, or you're programming for a system with a small amount of stack memory. Otherwise the benefits of destroying it quickly seem to be outweighed by the overhead of both calling a factory method and adding the code for such a method.

Comment: The object in my case is a physics body, which has a few mandatory traits (mass for instance) and a whole host of optional ones like velocity and position.  Using a definition object for that means I only need write one construction function, in the object's constructor.  I avoid the heap here because allocation is expensive.  (I agree the lambda is messy though.  if it's the only method, I'll just live with the definitions sitting in my function scope)

Comment: I can kind of see where you're coming from. You could try something like the prototype pattern (I like patterns),  but honestly the factory method patterns is your best option here. And if you're not ever reusing def, the utility of having only a single constructor doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score -2):

Something like that:

```
Object obj;
{
    ObjectDef def(importantData);  // should die as soon as obj is created
    def.setOptionalData(100);

    obj = Object(def);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Object has no default constructor, (only one constructor that takes the ObjectDef parameter) so the first line is a compiler error

Comment: @Clairvoire You could use this setup but wrap `Object` in a `boost::optional`. If you really really want to. I think it's not cleaner though.

Comment: @Clairvoire you can add dummy constructor `Object(){}`

Comment: @Randl but why do a construction and a copy when you could elide it and only do one?

Comment: @Randl It's not that simple. Maybe `Object` contains 50 objects that are all not default constructible.