# Compound statements vs unnamed lambdas

Tags: c++

Can we expect that compound statements / block scopes like this

```cpp
void foo(){
  {        //<---
    //...
  }        //<---
  //...
}
```

and unnamed lambdas like this

```cpp
void foo(){
  [&]{        //<---
    //...
  }();        //<---
  //...
}
```

always produce same code when optimization is on considering function call stack size? If not, which one shall be preferred?

The reason why I am asking is that when optimization is off stack size needed in compound statements is not going to be reclaimed see https://wandbox.org/permlink/PaychPU21SPnwDBU (for clang see https://wandbox.org/permlink/eSPwma7dboBHAXmh).

---

EDIT

Let me rephrase this. Does the second, in contrast to the first, guarantee to reclaim the stack size used inside the lambda?

Comment: I recommend you follow [the KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): Keep It Simple Sonny. The second example with an anonymous lambda isn't as simple as the first example.

Comment: As for optimizations, first write a simple and working program. Then if it's not "good enough" (which often *is* good enough) according to your requirements, then you start to profile and benchmark to find the top two or three (at most) bottlenecks, and optimize those. With plenty of documentation and comments, as optimizations often tend to make code quite obfuscated and non-intuitive.

Comment: In principle, there is little preventing a compiler from producing the same output given the two samples. In practice, it depends on quality of implementation (of the compiler). An implementation is not *required* to take every optimisation opportunity, and there is a cost (effort of compiler developers, measurable performance of the compiler) in doing so.  To be 100% sure, examine the compiler output with your favourite settings. That aside, I'd prefer the first option for readability (the second, at first glance, strikes me as a source file corrupted with line noise).

Comment: Given your program is compiler specific (not even clang compiles this code), you should ask about gcc specifically  and not lure people into thinking this is a general question.

Comment: @BitTickler Here you have it for clang https://wandbox.org/permlink/eSPwma7dboBHAXmh. I am sorry for luring you. I don't see why this should be too much compiler specific. Optimization specific yes, but that is also the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For your first comment: I totally agree in general, but here I'm not sure if it will also always produce the same code and probably the second will always produce better one. I'll be more than happy to add 6 characters to get better stack usage.

Comment: Remember that lambdas are really implemented using a compiler-generated class (with a suitable call operator). With an anonymous lambda you need to create a temporary object of this class, and will call its `operator()` function, and then the temporary object is destructed. In the first example there's no temporary objects and there's no function to call. Even if the call to the lambda could be inlined (not always guaranteed), it's still an extra object to keep track of for the compiler and the run-time code. So not really better usage of the stack IMO.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Usually such block scopes when used for stack usage optimization are not used for a single `std::string` like I did in the minimal verifiable example, but to get rid of KiB bytes and more. Therefore even if the lambda fails to inline and the temporary size fails to be reclaimed it would still be irrelevant compared to the size of the block scope potentially? not being reclaimed.

Comment: The standard never makes any guarantee about “function call stack size,” which is an implementation detail out of the scope of the standard.

Comment: I've just changed my code (for which this was intended for) from using approach #1 to approach #2 and it decreased function call stack size by half (with optimization on - gcc 7.4.0 and -O2). Basically it ended up doubling the capacity, which is great. Anyway I think its best to avoid it altogether as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072864/11101828.